# Postgres selection from array inside a user defined type

Tags: arrays, postgresql, types, nested

I have made a type and a table:

```
CREATE TYPE public.sample AS
(
    ts timestamp with time zone,
    temperature real[]
);
```

and a table using this type:

```
CREATE TABLE IF NOT EXISTS public.tc_sampling
(
    equip_id integer,
    tc_sample sample
)   
TABLESPACE pg_default;
```

and I can put data in like this:

```
INSERT INTO 
   tc_sampling (equip_id, tc_sample) 
VALUES 
   (10,('2022-12-30 11:45:56',
ARRAY[109.4,140.98,144.17,62.25,93.12,61.47,65.1,59.42,79.61]::real[]))
```

but I don't know how to select, for instance, just the timestamp or one of the items in the temperature real [] array.

when I do a full, select, I do get data:

> SELECT * FROM tc_sampling limit 3;
>
> 10   "(""2022-12-30 11:45:46-05"",""{109.3,140.88,144.17,62.25,93.12,61.47,65.1,59.42,79.61}"")"
>
> 10   "(""2022-12-30 11:45:56-05"",""{110.47,141.89,146.2,62.34,94.01,63.17,65.5,60.03,85.69}"")"
>
> 10   "(""2022-12-30 11:46:06-05"",""{113.24,144.13,149.42,62.5,95.5,66.6,65.99,61.79,98.3}"")"

I have tried, for instance,

```
SELECT equip_id,tc_sample[1]FROM tc_sampling  limit 10;
```

and got

```
ERROR:  cannot subscript type sample because it does not support subscripting
LINE 1: SELECT equip_id,tc_sample[1]FROM tc_sampling  limit 10;
                         ^
SQL state: 42804
Character: 17
```

and

```
SELECT (ARRAY[tc_sample])[1:1]
FROM tc_sampling
WHERE equip_id=10
LIMIT 3
```

and got:

> "{""(""2022-12-30 11:45:46-05"",""{109.3,140.88,144.17,62.25,93.12,61.47,65.1,59.42,79.61}"")""}"
> "{""(""2022-12-30 11:45:56-05"",""{110.47,141.89,146.2,62.34,94.01,63.17,65.5,60.03,85.69}"")""}"
> "{""(""2022-12-30 11:46:06-05"",""{113.24,144.13,149.42,62.5,95.5,66.6,65.99,61.79,98.3}"")""}"

Answer (score 0):

```
CREATE TYPE public.sample AS
(
    ts timestamp with time zone,
    temperature real[]
);
CREATE TABLE IF NOT EXISTS public.tc_sampling
(
    equip_id integer,
    tc_sample sample
)   ;
INSERT INTO 
   tc_sampling (equip_id, tc_sample) 
VALUES 
   (10,('2022-12-30 11:45:56',
ARRAY[109.4,140.98,144.17,62.25,93.12,61.47,65.1,59.42,79.61]::real[]));

select (tc_sampling.tc_sample).ts from tc_sampling ;
           ts            
-------------------------
 12/30/2022 11:45:56 PST

select (tc_sampling.tc_sample).temperature from tc_sampling ;
                       temperature                        
----------------------------------------------------------
 {109.4,140.98,144.17,62.25,93.12,61.47,65.1,59.42,79.61}
```

Per documentation [Field selection](https://www.postgresql.org/docs/current/sql-expressions.html#FIELD-SELECTION)

> 4.2.4. Field Selection

...

> (Thus, a qualified column reference is actually just a special case of the field selection syntax.) An important special case is extracting a field from a table column that is of a composite type:

> (compositecol).somefield
> (mytable.compositecol).somefield

> The parentheses are required here to show that compositecol is a column name not a table name, or that mytable is a table name not a schema name in the second case.

Comment: Thank you, kindly! (and quickly!) 
I also see this works: 
select (tc_sampling.tc_sample).temperature[1] from tc_sampling;